# Python List Index Out of Range When In Range

Tags: python

I'm debugging my program which converts input excel file to output csv file.
In the reformatting part of the program, it gives an error saying IndexError: list index out of range.

I put a try-except loop to see where the program is getting stuck. It first gets stuck when the program finds that len(x) is 45500; however, i is only 12500. I'm really confused why the program would get stuck at this point since i should be in the range of len(x). Furthermore, when the break in the except portion of the loop is removed to allow the program run to completion, the except loop keeps printing out len(x) which is 45500 and i which finally ends at 45499. Even then, i should be in the range.

Make_csv is the function where the problem is occurring; the 2 functions above it is where the matrix is being created. Matrix[0] is a 1 x 45500 matrix reading the first column of data from the excel input file. Matrix[1] is a 1 x 12500 matrix reading the second column of the file.

Any help is appreciated.

```
def create_mat(columns, sets):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(sets):
        ncolT = "Time%d" % (i + 1)  # from 1 to ..
        ncolD = "Data%d" % (i + 1)  # from 1 to ..

        if len(columns[ncolT]) == len(columns[ncolD]):
            length = len(columns[ncolT])
            x = []
            y = []

            # read the time
            print(ncolD + '--' + ncolT)
            svline = 0
            for j in columns[ncolT]:
                svline = svline + 1
                print(svline)
                j = j.replace(',', '.')
                '''
                while True:
                    print(j)
                    except ValueError,j:
                        print("error")
                '''
                print(j)
                try:
                    fNum = round(float(j), 1)
                except ValueError:
                    print("error")
                x.append(fNum)
                # x.append(fNum+0.1)

            # read the values measured
            for j in columns[ncolD]:
                try:
                    j = j.replace(',', '.')
                    fNum = float(j)
                    y.append(fNum)
                except ValueError:
                    print("error")

            matrix.append(x)
            matrix.append(y)

        else:
            print("Column sizes are not matching")
    return matrix


def unify_dataset(matrix, sets):
    uni_x = []
    uni_y = []
    dt = 0
    dy = 0

    # align y values at zero
    dy = matrix[1][0]

    # unify partial measurements
    for i in range(sets):
        cur_x = matrix[2 * i]
        cur_y = matrix[2 * i + 1]
        if i > 0:
            dt += cur_x[len(cur_x) - 1]

        for j in range(len(cur_x)):
            uni_x.append(cur_x[j] + dt)

        for j in range(len(cur_y)):
            uni_y.append(cur_y[j] - dy)
            print(uni_y[j])

    # Extent the end of the measurement
    timer = uni_x[-1]
    last = uni_y[-1]

    drop_const = (uni_y[-10] - uni_y[-1]) / (0.2 * 10)
    print(timer)
    print(last)
    print(drop_const)
    print("debug")

    matrix = []
    matrix.append(uni_x)
    matrix.append(uni_y)

    print(matrix)
    print(matrix[0])
    print(matrix[1])

    return matrix


def make_csv(filename, headers, matrix):
  with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(["time (s)", "response (nm)"])
    x = matrix[0]
    y = matrix[1]
    print(len(y))

    for i in range(len(x)):
      try:
          xstr = "%.1f" % (x[i])
          xstr = xstr.replace('.', ',')
          ystr = "%.4f" % (y[i])
          ystr = ystr.replace('.', ',')
          spamwriter.writerow([xstr, ystr])
      except IndexError:
          print("index error")
          print(len(x))
          print(i)
          #break
```

Comment: What are `matrix[0]` and `matrix[1]`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: For the record, what's `len(y)`?

Comment: Your posted code merely defines a function and quits without executing.  You've failed to provide the full error message.  Please update.  We have no evidence that `x` is the problem length; in fact, from what little you've given us, it *should* be `y`.

Comment: I've added more information. Hopefully, this helps.